# Running virtual machine on separated disk from HyperV

Tags: windows, virtualization, hyper-v

i want to setup server that have 4 SSDs. On one SSD i will install Windows Server(Host) with Hyper-V on it and on other 3 SSDs i will install(SQL Server(Windows Server), Dev environment(Windows 10) and Hosting(Windows Server)) each environment will be on it's own SSD.

Question is, will there be benefits from this approach?
Or there is maybe better approach?

I' am not familiar with this things so any advice would be great or some link to point me.

Thx :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an extremely 'unhealthy' design. You'll have 4 SPOFs, you'll steal IOPS from your production applications, and you'll have 4 separate silos of storage to manage. Boot from mirrored el cheapo SATA DOMs (32-64GB should be OK), and add your 4 SSDs into RAID5 or RAID10 volume.

Comment: RAID 5 is dead, and its write pattern is pretty trash for virtualization, much less virtualization with database workloads. I would even go one step farther and condense the entire system to a single RAID 10 if there's already going to be one present. However, the use of Storage Spaces and ReFS would actually make an effort to preserve data integrity.

Comment: @BaronSamedi1958 Could you explain what is " mirrored el cheapo SATA DOMs" or can you provide some link if it's to much to write?

Comment: @SmallLoanOf1M RAID5 used with high-capacity HDDs is an ugly and dangerous design choice indeed. However, if you need a balance between performance and usable capacity, RAID5 is still a very feasible option if used with SSDs and modern RAID controllers.

Comment: "RAID 5 is dead" unfortunately you have no idea what you're talking about :) RAID5 is absolutely OK for SSDs, and every SSD uses single party RAID inside for raw flash cells. 1) https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/raid-5-was-great-until-high-capacity-hdds-came-into-play-but-ssds-restored-its-former-glory-2 2) http://www.computerweekly.com/feature/SSD-RAID-essentials-What-you-need-to-know-about-flash-and-RAID

Comment: "Could you explain what is..." Sure! Something like this... https://www.supermicro.com/products/nfo/SATADOM.cfm

Comment: @BaronSamedi1958 Resorting to an ad-honinem attack right out the gate isn't the most reasonable option. It's not as if I insulted your mother, unless you're actually a RAID controller in disguise. While faster SSDs allow for RAID5 to still be viable in the short term, that's going to change for implementation and density - RAID 5 doesn't scale too well, as we've demonstrated over and over again by running into scaling issues. Also keep in mind that while several lines of SSDs use single parity, not ALL of them do. Single parity is also not RAID 5, R5 just employs single parity in its system.

Comment: None of this is even considering data integrity, which RAID makes no promise of. Since this question is about approach, it's reasonable to consider approaches other than hardware RAID cards - hardware cards being chronically out of date with very little recourse for tight EOL cycles, and often left behind in infrastructure patching.